# Что то не так в запросе MySQL

Tags: запрос, mysql

```
$tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  dialogues WHERE id1='$myrow2[id]' AND          id2='myrow[id]' OR id2='$myrow2[id]' AND id1='myrow[id]' ORDER BY id1 DESC",$db);
```

Comment: что тут не так скажите пожалуйста не выводит данные запрос?(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы переодически забываете указывать знак $ перед именем переменной.
Ключи массива заключайте в кавычки.
Не забывайте использовать скобки для группировки условий.
Если я правильно угадал ход ваших мыслей, то попробуйте вот так:

```
$tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                    FROM dialogues
                    WHERE (id1='{$myrow2['id']}' AND id2='{$myrow['id']}') OR
                          (id1='{$myrow['id']}' AND id2='{$myrow2['id']}')
                    ORDER BY id1 DESC",$db);
```

Comment: Ооо спасибо!! Глаза совсем замылились не разглядел такую явную ошибку! видимо от того что писал скрипт в 4 часа утра - вот такое и вылезло))